# SSH server and localhost

Tags: ssh, server, localhost

I tried to install a SSH server on WSL, it never worked. So i installed my SSH server on my laptop and i try to connect, it doesn't work either. But it works from my phone on 4G or everything expect my computer on local

I get this error everytime, either with WSL Debian ou Windows :

ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: This is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the question to ask on Stackoverflow. However, check your firewall allowance.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not know i can't ask to that subject. Thx for your advice anyway

Comment: First, try to just disable firewall, and let me know if it helps.

Comment: The screen is in french, it just said all the firewall is disabled. And it doesn't work :https://i.imgur.com/MM1cAwX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first this [OpenSSH Windows installation guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server):

It includes a network configuration:

> Allow incoming connections to SSH server in Windows Firewall:

> When installed as an optional feature, the firewall rule “`OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)`” should have been created automatically.
> If not, proceed to create and enable the rule as follows.
>
> - Either run the following PowerShell command as the Administrator:
>
>   ```
>   New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH SSH Server' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22 -Program "C:\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe"
>   ```
>
>   Replace `C:\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe` with the actual path to the `sshd.exe` (C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe, had you followed the manual installation instructions above).
> - or go to `Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall1 > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules` and add a new rule for port 22.

Then you can check if at least your SSH daemon can receive anything.

---

The [OP SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13447467/srp) adds in [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219820/discussion-between-srp-and-vonc):

> The problem turned out to be other machine with same IP address as the server."
> I cheated and it works: I used a VPN.

Comment: Thx for these advice but i am not looking for create a ssh server on wsl, just to connect to one in my WSL.

Comment: @SRP Yes, connect to an SSH server running on your workstation, right?

Comment: Yes. The setup is : SSH server is on my laptop, and i want to connect to it with my "main computer". It works from my phone, my computer with dualboot Debian, Windows, just not in WSL (the one i want).

Sorry for my english, i hope you'll understand my problem

Comment: @SRP No problem, and your english is quite good (I am French anyway). So the answer stands, and the idea is to activated sshd in debug mode on your laptop, in order to read why that SSH daemon refuses your connection. If nothing appears, there would be a network/firewall issue between the main computer and the laptop, hence the firewall rules (to relax the destination laptop rules and allow requests to port 22 to go through)

Comment: Thanks i will try. The main problem is that it works perfectly well from my phone on 4G but not in wifi

Comment: On the service ssh status, i got this problem :

août 14 13:47:37 srp-pc sshd[1036]: Unable to negotiate with 218.92.0.248 port 13035: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-ex>

Comment: @SRP How about `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@server`? The source (client) seems to use an old SSH (https://askubuntu.com/a/891591/5470)

Comment: Nothing different. I thought the same about old ssh client but i use Debian on WSL 2, and i update/upgrade to unstable version so ?

Comment: @SRP OK, what is the version of the ssh client, and of the ssh daemon server?

Comment: On the client : 8.3 
On the server : The sshd_config said : v1.103 2018/04/09
But it's maybe only the config file and not the server ? I didn't find the command like "ssh -V" 

I use the unstable version on Debian, my sources.list is : 

# See https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList for more information.
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

Comment: Let's make a screen : https://i.imgur.com/hhagvb7.png

Comment: @SRP Maybe the sshd on the server side is too restrictive in term of keys? (as in https://serverfault.com/a/994935/783) (check its `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`) Also check AllowGroups (https://serverfault.com/a/861548/783) A 8.3 on your Debian WSL2 client should work. Not sure about port 13035 though... Should be port 22.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219820/discussion-between-srp-and-vonc).